# Invoke-command -ArgumentList parameter syntax

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting

I'm trying to add multiple csv-imported lists to a remote executed PS script. It works fine when I pass only one list using the following command:

```
Invoke-Command -filepath $createSAPSPath -ConnectionUri $uri -Credential $credential -ArgumentList (,$accountsList)
```

What would be the correct syntax for multiple list objects? I've tried:

```
Invoke-Command -filepath $createSAPSPath -ConnectionUri $uri -Credential $credential -ArgumentList (,$accountsList),(,$groupsList)
```

But it doesn't seem to work...

Thanks,

Glenn

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have to realize why you need unary comma in the first situation, to understand why its not needed in the second one.

Parameter `-ArgumentList` takes `Object[]` argument type. If you are passing single collection, you need to prevent PowerShell from treating single argument (that happens to be a collection) as collection of arguments passed to this parameter.

If you pass something that is collection already (e.g. `$AnyObject, $EvenCollection`), regardless of the type of individual objects, PowerShell will do what users usually expect: pass first collection to first parameter, second collection to the second parameter.

To sum it up: you should be able to run this like that:

```
Invoke-Command -filepath $createSAPSPath -ConnectionUri $uri -Credential $credential -ArgumentList $accountsList, $groupList
```

... and get expected results.

Answer (score 4):

Try it this way:

```
$AccountList = 'Account1','Account2'
$GroupList    = 'Group1','Group2'

invoke-command {$args[0];'*****';$args[1]} -ArgumentList (,$AccountList,$GroupList) 

Account1
Account2
*****
Group1
Group2
```

Answer (score 0):

Another one...

```
$myArrList = [System.Collections.ArrayList]@()
$myArrList2 = [System.Collections.ArrayList]@()

//add your elements here

$arguments = @()
$arguments += (,$myArrList)
$arguments += (,$myArrList2)

$j = Start-Job -Name $('job-' +$env:COMPUTERNAME) -ScriptBlock $scriptBlockJob -ArgumentList $arguments
```