# Files not getting deleted from remote servers

Tags: powershell

I have written the following script using a post on this forum. The script deletes the files which are older than 15 days:

```psh
cls
$servers = Get-Content server.txt
$limit = (Get-Date).AddDays(-15)
$path = "E:\CheckDBOutput"

ForEach ($line in $servers)
{
  Invoke-Command -cn $line -ScriptBlock {
    Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Recurse -Force | Where-Object {
      !$_.PSIsContainer -and $_.CreationTime -lt $limit
    } | Remove-Item -Force
  }
}
```

The script is executing fine, but no files are getting deleted.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Invoke-command -ArgumentList parameter syntax](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23761109/invoke-command-argumentlist-parameter-syntax). You need to pass your variables as arguments to the script block

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already mentioned in the comments, you need to pass the parameters to use inside the scriptblock as arguments to the `-ArgumentList` parameter:

```
$RemoveOldFiles = {
  param(
    [string]$path,
    [datetime]$limit
  )

  Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Recurse -Force | Where-Object {
    !$_.PSIsContainer -and $_.CreationTime -lt $limit
    } | Remove-Item -Force
}

$servers = Get-Content server.txt
$limit = (Get-Date).AddDays(-15)
$path = "E:\CheckDBOutput"

ForEach ($line in $servers)
{
  Invoke-Command -cn $line -ScriptBlock $RemoveOldFiles -ArgumentList $path,$limit
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove-Item does not exist in PowerShell version 1.0 - make sure your destination servers have v2.0 or better installed.